# What's the integral of $(df/dx)^2$?

Tags: integration

I tried to calculate the value of $$\int_0^1\left(\frac{df}{dx}-u\right)^2\,dx$$

First I tried to expand it, and the first part is $$\int_0^1\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2\,dx$$

I don't know how to do the integration for that, so I input this expression [into Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(df%2Fdx)%5E2).

To my surprise, Wolfram says *there is no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions.*

Does anyone have ideas about what is the value of $$\int_0^1\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2\,dx$$ and how to calculate that?

Comment: I don't think there is any explicit expression of this integral for all function $f$, however, we can set some bounds on $f$ if it satisfies some specific conditions (e.g. If f(0)=f(1)=0, [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions) shall give a good bound).

Comment: Squaring has no reason to be compatible with integration. For instance, $$ \int \left( e^x - \frac{1}{x} \right) \, dx = e^x - \log x + C $$ is an elementary function while $$ \int \left( e^x - \frac{1}{x} \right)^2 \, dx = e^x - \frac{1}{x} - 2 \operatorname{Ei}(x) + C, $$ where $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ is the exponential integral and it is proved that it cannot be written in elementary terms. Definite integrals are slightly better in this regard but you still cannot expect much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea that the comment by @SangchulLee. A closed-form for $\int(f')^2$ will give a closed-form formula for $\int fg$ when $\int f$ and $\int g$ have closed-form solutions because
$$fg = \frac14((f + g)^2 - (f - g)^2),$$
but this is impossible:
$$\int \sin x\,dx,\qquad \int\frac 1x\,dx$$
*have* closed-form solutions, while
$$\int\frac{\sin x}x\,dx$$
does *not have*.